# Beginner in networking please help - file sharing

Tags: networking, command-line, server, file-sharing

Hello I am new to Linux Ubuntu, I have a spare PC laying around and I wanted to make it a file/media sharing server.
 I cannot even figure out how to get Ubuntu to see my windows 8 pc nor can I get my windows 8 to see my ubuntu. I need step by step instructions on how to set everything up.

Comment: Look up SAMBA and CIFS, e.g. http://www.thatsquality.com/articles/mounting-windows-smb-file-shares-using-cifs

Answer (score 0):

You need to have both machine in same network and shared folder on windows8 machine.

here’s what you need to run:

`apt-get install samba4` to get the latest version of Samba.

`apt-get install cifs-utils` to get necessary files/utils required to mount Windows shares.

Then do the following:

```
mkdir /mnt/share
```

Type the following command to mount the share:

```
mount -t cifs //windowsmachineip/sharename -o username=user,password=urPassword /mnt/share
```

On older machines the shares could be mounted as follows:

```
mount -t smbfs -o username=user,password=urPassword //windowsmachineip/sharename /mnt/share
```